# Chrome Extensions Manifest File Permissions Match doesn't work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and so far my goal is trying to apply the extension to only URLs with "http://www.facebook.com/events/*".

This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "my extension",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "myextension",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://www.facebook.com/events/*"
    ]
}
```

However, when I try to apply my extension to just "http://www.facebook.com/", the extension continue to run and give out unwanted actions. What do you think is going on? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `However, when I try to apply my extension to just "http://www.facebook.com/", the extension continue to run and give out unwanted actions.`? Where does it continue to run on? Why would you change it to `http://www.facebook.com` if you wanted it to apply to `http://www.facebook.com/events/*`

Comment: I meant I did not change permissions to `"http://www.facebook.com"`, and so I completely expect it to NOT run on `"http://www.facebook.com"`. My extension uses executeScript to inject some javascript into its intended websites, so I don't want my extension to run if it's just `"http://www.facebook.com"`. However, when I load the extension and navigate to facebook.com, the extension runs even when i've specified its permission to be `"http://www.facebook.com/events/*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the background page references some JavaScript (or has JavaScript directly in it) that is still running?

The reason is that the `permissions` you have set for is the `tabs`, the background page will always load regardless of this permission.  If you want to prevent the code on the background page from loading then you need to do something like this:

Either only include the script when the browser action is clicked:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //do something
});
```

Or prevent the script from loading only on the pages you want:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("//www.facebook.com/events/") > -1) {
    // do something         
    }
});
```